# How to test that function provided by context has been invoked inside a custom hook that is firing a network request using React Query Mutation

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library, react-query, msw

I am testing a custom hook called `useRequest` that's responsible for sending a particular request.
It looks like this:

```js
export const useRequest = () => {
  const {
    updateContextState
  } = useSomeContext()
  const {
    isLoading,
    mutate,
    isSuccess
  } = useMutation(someRequest, {
    onSuccess: (res) => {
      updateContextState(res)
    }
  })

  const sendRequest = () => {
    ...aditional code...
    mutate()
  }

  return {
    sendRequest,
    isLoading,
    isSuccess
  }
}
```

**App.ts:**

```js
export const App = () => < SomeProvider > ... < /SomeProvider>
```

**useRequest.test.tsx:**

```js
/* eslint-disable import/order */
import {
  AllTheProviders,
  renderHook,
  act,
  MockReactQueryProvider,
  waitFor
} from 'test-utils/test-utils'
import {
  SomeContext
} from 'context/SomeContext'
import {
  rest
} from 'msw'
import {
  setupServer
} from 'msw/node'
import useRequest from './useContinueRequest'
import {
  ReactNode
} from 'react'
import {
  BrowserRouter
} from 'react-router-dom'
import {
  QueryClient,
  QueryClientProvider
} from 'react-query'

const server = setupServer(
  rest.post(
    'http://localhost:3000/api/getData',
    (_req, res, ctx) => {
      return res(ctx.delay(500), ctx.status(200), ctx.json({
        greeting: 'hello there'
      }))
    }
  )
)

const queryClient = new QueryClient({
  defaultOptions: {
    queries: {
      retryDelay: 1,
      retry: 0
    }
  }
})

const updateContextStateMock = jest.fn()
const mockContextValues = {
  updateContextState: updateContextStateMock,
}
const wrapper = ({
  children
}: {
  children: ReactNode
}) => ( <
  QueryClientProvider client = {
    queryClient
  } >
  <
  BrowserRouter >
  <
  SomeContext.Provider value = {
    mockContextValues
  } > {
    children
  } <
  /SomeContext.Provider> <
  /BrowserRouter> <
  /QueryClientProvider>
)

beforeAll(() => server.listen())
afterEach(() => {
  server.resetHandlers()
  queryClient.clear()
})
afterAll(() => server.close())

describe('useRequest', () => {
  test('sendContinueRequest is being called', async() => {
    const {
      result
    } = renderHook(() => useRequest(), {
      wrapper
    })

    await act(async() => {
      await result.current.sendRequest()
    })

    await waitFor(
      async() => {
        await expect(result.current.isSuccess).toBeTruthy()
      }, {
        timeout: 1000
      }
    )

    expect(updateContextState).toHaveBeenCalled()
  })
})
```

As you can see I'm awaiting for request to be successfull, which I've assured actually happenes through debugging.
But for some reason `updateContextState` function is never being fired?
Thanks for any help

I've tried the code I've simplified above, however I couldn't get `updateContextState` to be fired

EDIT:
If I put `updateContextState` inside `sendRequest` function like so the test passes:

```
  const sendRequest = () => {
    ...aditional code...
    updateContextState() <- 
    mutate()
  }
```

So I guess it has something to do with async code not being resolved